# javascript append text to key's value in object

Tags: javascript, object

I have this object

```
var data = 
{
    Brand: "Toyota", 
    Count: 28042, 
    GBV: 1524
};
```

What I want to do with it is modify 'Count: 28042' by appending 'cars sold' after the 28042.

This is what I have:

```
if (data.Brand == 'Toyota') {
            var itemCount = data.Count;
            //add "cars sold" to itemCount      
        }
```

Expected output:

```
var data = 
{
    Brand: "Toyota", 
    Count: 28042 cars sold, 
    GBV: 1524
};
```

Basically same behavior as 'push' except this isn't an array so it won't work on object. The difference between what I am trying accomplish versus what I've researched is that I don't want the output key/value to be an array. I want '28042 cars sold' as the complete value of the key.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ptcyebj/

Comment: just a simple concatenation?

Answer (score 0):

You simply assign the new value to the property. We are creating the new value by reading the current value first:

```
data.Count = data.Count + " cars sold";
```

You can even use the shorthand assignment operator since you want to *append*:

```
data.Count += " cars sold";
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to append `' cars sold'` to `data.Count`: `data.Count += ' cars sold';`

Answer (score 0):

You can just update your `if` statement to the following:

```
if (data.Brand == 'Toyota') {
     //add "cars sold" to itemCount
     data.Count = data.Count + " cars sold";
 }
```

See complete code below:

```js
var data = {
  Brand: "Toyota",
  Count: 28042,
  GBV: 1524
};


if (data.Brand == 'Toyota') {
  //add "cars sold" to itemCount
  data.Count = data.Count + " cars sold";
}

console.log(data);
```